# Is there a way to make stitching?

Tags: sculpting

So other than taking time and sculpting an entire object to make stitches, is there a quicker way to do it? Blender should make a stitch sculpt though if there is no quick way.

Answer (score 9):

With version 2.78, you can now draw curves onto surfaces.

To use it:

1. Add a Path curve in object mode (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> >> Curve >> Path).
2. Enter into edit mode (<kbd>TAB</kbd>).
3. <kbd>T</kbd> to show the Tools panel.
4. Under the **Options** tab set your **Projection Depth** to Surface.
5. Under the **Create** tab click **Draw Curve** or alternatively <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> >> Draw Curve.

**NOTE**: you can play with the Tolerance under the **Options** tab to get settings to your liking. After creating your desired curve, delete the verts that make up the original path.

6. Create a thread mesh design.
7. Add an **Array** modifier to your thread mesh, setting its **Fit Type** to the curve object.
8. Add a **Curve** modifier to the thread mesh, setting its **Object** to the same curve object in the Array modifier.

For me, I picked the start point of my curve as being the origin of the curve, and set its position to the origin of the thread mesh, then played with the **Constant Offset** of the **Array** modifier.

Here's was my results:

[image]

Comment: related: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tAsUGy7XGOA

Answer (score 7):

My normal approach is to load up an alpha texture and subdivide my sculpt pretty heavily. I use Rake for the texture, and set spacing by trial and error here depending on the image used - this one was just from rendering a cube from top ortho view with some bevel on the edges.[image: example]
and the image used is [image: cube stitch]