# Trying to sculpt seams into a jacket with alphas and failing. Help?

Tags: texturing, transparency, sculpting

I'm trying to sculpt strips of seams with stitching using alphas into a high poly jacket that I plan to later retopo and bake the normals ([I've seen Zbrush users do it here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G3uOH8cir78&t=13s)). I can't quite get the settings right with the sculpting tools (such as curves and stencil mapping) to replicate what's in the alpha [(here's the alpha if you'd like to give it a try)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BXpNSSXVzlQ9Z7eqFRqPRWsIci787Cab/view?usp=sharing). You can see my results in the zig-zag looking area below (the others seams were done by hand and I don't enjoy that process). If you have any tips, that would be great (or a better way of getting realistic seams in leather jackets). Thanks[image]

Comment: Can you post a photo of what you want as the result ?

Comment: Sure thing! You see the seams going down the arm and where the shoulder area is in the photo in the link below? I'm going for that. https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81gPumH6e1L._AC_UL1500_.jpg

Comment: I'm not sure your image works right for what you're trying to do...

Comment: here it is : https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/72121/is-there-a-way-to-make-stitching/72123

Comment: Hey hamed, those settings helped a lot! Thanks bunches! One less headache to worry about!